# 当サイトを改善するための提案

Tags: サポート, プライベートベータ, 使い勝手

ご存知の通り、スタック・オーバーフローが[英語から始まりました](http://stackoverflow.com)。当サイトを日本語にするためは和訳のみではなく、使い手も日本人に合うように目指しています。

例えば、日本語で書いている時、変換をします。リストが出てきて、選択された漢字を「Enter」で決定しますが、英語版のサイトでコメント欄に「Enter」を押すと変換中にも関わらずコメントを投稿してしまいます。日本人ならイライラするので、使い手の悪いところをスタック・オーバーフローMetaにて[質問を投稿してください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)。

**下記のタグを適用してください：**

[機能の要求](/questions/tagged/%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e6%b1%82)[使い勝手](/questions/tagged/%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e5%8b%9d%e6%89%8b)

スクリーンショットも添付すれば、助かります。どう直せばベストかもご教示頂ければ最高です。

ご協力よろしくお願い致します！

Comment: 「使い手」より「使い勝手」が通りがよいと思います

Comment: 編集しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: あと「機能の要求」より「機能要望」か「要望」でしょうか。ああ、悩んでいたら「要望」という単語がゲシュタルト崩壊し始めた..